# Взаимозаменяемые тире и запятые. Что делать, чтобы максимально сохранить интонацию автора?

Tags: пунктуация

> Так я была поражена в Сиене на выставке замков – дверных замков,
>   амбарных, от ящиков, от сундуков. **Один из них – вероятно от какой-то
>   невысокой двери, он был раскрыт – беззащитно отдавал на суд зрителя
>   своё нехитрое устройство.** Вся внутренняя поверхность замка была
>   украшена вязью гравировки… Вероятно, человек увидел бы её за жизнь
>   несколько раз: когда замок пришлось бы смазать и когда починить.
>   Впрочем, не сомневаюсь, что работает он до сих пор.

*Один из них, вероятно от какой-то невысокой двери, – он был раскрыт, беззащитно отдавал на суд зрителя своё нехитрое устройство*, -

мой вариант, которым я недовольна...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется, что можно так:
**Один из них — вероятно от какой-то невысокой двери, — был раскрыт и беззащитно отдавал на суд зрителя своё нехитрое устройство.**

Или можно использовать скобки, если в предыдущем тексте ими не злоупотребляли:
**Один из них (вероятно от какой-то невысокой двери) был раскрыт и беззащитно отдавал на суд зрителя своё нехитрое устройство.**

И ещё. В первом предложении, думаю, можно слово "замков" после тире безболезненно убрать:
**Так я была поражена в Сиене на выставке замков – дверных, амбарных, от ящиков, от сундуков.**

Comment: ВЕРОЯТНО -- вводное. В обоих предложенных Вами вариантах после него нужна запятая. А вот запятую после **двери** в первом варианте, думаю, стоит убрать.

Comment: Вы знаете, я сомневалась. Галина ТАК всегда печётся об авторском тексте, что боишься лишний раз не в ту сторону подумать.

Comment: Римуль, Слава ВСЕГДА прав. Жаль, что он редко к нам заглядывает. В моём варианте правки запятая после "вероятно" не стоит - обособление происходит вместе с содержимым вероятности, а в двух Ваших вариантах "вероятно" попало в скобки и в два тире - запятая ставится обязательно. И после "двери" зпт делать абсолютно нечего; у меня же зап-тире стоят перед "он": *Один из них,  трам-пам-пам, – он был раскрыт...*

Comment: Кто бы сомневался в том, что **Слава всегда прав**! Конечно, после "вероятно" необходима запятая. Я почти год **пытаюсь соответствовать**, но с моим глобальным (почти четвертьвековым) отсутствием в ареале русского — это очень сложно.

Comment: А Слава не хочет оформить свою рекомендацию как ответ? Мне импонирует такой вариант.

Answer (score 2):

1) Один из них, **вероятно от какой-то невысокой двери,**  был раскрыт и беззащитно отдавал на суд зрителя своё нехитрое устройство.

2) Один из них – **раскрытый, вероятно от какой-то невысокой двери** – беззащитно отдавал на суд зрителя своё нехитрое устройство.

3) 1) Один из них, **вероятно от какой-то невысокой двери, был раскрыт –** и   беззащитно отдавал на суд зрителя своё нехитрое устройство.

Comment: Жасминочка, автор хочет сохранить вот это дыхание: *...он был раскрыт – беззащитно отдавал на суд зрителя своё нехитрое устройство".*